# couchdb/cloudant time series querying

Tags: couchdb, time-series, cloudant

I have a cloudant database containing a collection of measures coming in from multiple devices.
Each device sends many measures but three are of interest : temperature, latitude and longitude.
Due to the design of the system, each value is a separate measure (I cannot easily join temperature, latitude and longitude at insertion time) and in the database I have a set of measures like so:

```
{
  "device": "foo",
  "name": "temperature",
  "date": <timestamp>,
  "value": <value>
},
{
  "device": "foo",
  "name": "latitude",
  "date": <timestamp>,
  "value": <value>
},
{
  "device": "foo",
  "name": "longitude",
  "date": <timestamp>,
  "value": <value>
},
```

So conceptually, I have 3 time series.
I would like to extract the **latest** measure of each of these time series, and ideally have them grouped by device.

Something like:

```
{
  device1: {
    "temperature": {
      date: <date>,
      value: <value>
    },
    "latitude": {
      date: <date>,
      value: <value>
    },
   "longitude": {
      date: <date>,
      value: <value>
   }
  },
  "device2": {
    ...
  }
}
```

I do not expect this exact syntax, that's just an idea of the set of data I'm expecting.

I could join the positional measures together but the question would be the same: how to get the last ts entries of each device grouped together?

Comment: Just to be sure, the *last ts* stands for last timestamp?

Comment: no, I meant the last timeserie entry by date of course (which is more or less the same)

Comment: And last question before I answer to your problem, the "Date" entry for each mesure isn't the same  for every values in one entry ? Shouldn't it be :  {
  "_id": "123909012",
  "device1": {
    "latitude": "",
    "longitude": "",
    "temperature": ""
  },
  "device2": {
    "latitude": "",
    "longitude": "",
    "temperature": ""
  }
}

Comment: no, the date might be different for each value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first place, I would use a data structure like this :

```
{
    "type":"temperature",
    "date":"1472528116698",
    "value":"35",
    "device":"device1"
}
```

The type property could be either temperature,latitude,longitude.

Then you need some views. Personally, I prefer to have one _design documents by **type** and it will also be easier for the queries.

For example, you would have a _design document like this for the temperature :

```
{
   "_id": "_design/temperature",
   "_rev": "8-91e594df623063ed3ad7111cde09eecb",
   "language": "javascript",
   "views": {
       "byDevice": {
           "map": "function(doc) {\n    if ((doc.type + '').toLowerCase() === 'temperature' && doc.device)\n        emit(doc.device);\n}\n"
       },
       "lastestByDevice": {
           "map": "function(doc) {\n    if ((doc.type + '').toLowerCase() === 'temperature' && doc.device && doc.value)\n        emit(doc.device,doc.value);\n}\n",
           "reduce": "function(keys, values, rereduce) {\n    var max = Number.MIN_VALUE;\n    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {\n        var val = parseFloat(values[i]);\n        if (val > max)\n            max = val;\n    }\n    return max;\n}\n"
       }
   }
}
```

Request example:

> http://localhost:5984/db/_design/temperature/_view/latestByDevice?group_level=1&reduce=true

If you use the latest by device with the reduce function, it would return each device with their maximum value. We this example, you should be able to get a good start. I don't know how you receive and build your data but if you prefer to group everything by device, it's also possible.

Comment: I actually came to a similar solution of implementing a reduce function as a "retain the most recent measure" function.
However it is considered a "questionnable" practice to implement reduce functions, I was hoping there would be a solution that didn't need to do that

Comment: Using views without reduce functions seems unfortunatly not a good idea since i read somewhere that the key were stocked as string. So when comes the time to sort the key, i doubt this would work but I could give it a try tonight.